# LoggingHandler and it's effect on handlers further down the pipeline

Tags: netty

I'm testing a TcpClient that uses netty (against a TCP server that is written in Rust). The clients sends LengthPrefixed messages in a burst (without waiting for responses) and then processes the responses as they arrive.

Strangely, some of the messages never get a response (but I'm pretty sure the responses have arrived from the server but are never delivered to the handler).  Now, if I introduce a LoggingHandler into the chain, things start working, so just wondering if the LoggingHandler in anyway changes the behaviour of handlers further down the pipeline. BTW, things also work if I introduce a small delay (say 100ms) between two requests. Any pointers/insights will be helpful.

The pipeline is quite simple - **LoggingHandler->LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder->TcpClientChannelInboundHandler**

(The code is available here - https://github.com/rkbalgi/tcpasync/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/rkbalgi/tcpasync/client/TcpClient.java#L80 and test is here - https://github.com/rkbalgi/tcpasync/blob/master/src/test/java/TcpClientTest.java#L82)

I'm using **netty-4.1.51** on **Windows 10**.

**Update** - Some messages never got a response because they were never sent out :). Looks like the problem may be related to doing too many concurrent writeAndFlush() without checking the result of those. Adding a sync() appears to fix the issue. Still investigating.

Comment: This totally ended up being a non-issue. The issue happened to be on the Rust side of things :-/

Couple of lessons learnt though - 
*  Always check the returned future from writeAndFlush() either by adding a listener or calling sync() on it
*   Use wireshark/pcap to ensure that the data makes it from one side to another!

Answer (score 0):

No the `LoggingHandler` has no other effect than logging.